# Js, Bootstrap: Do action each time while opening tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I create animations in Bootstrap tabs, animation should work each time while selecting each tab. But animation is working only first time, it's not working if I opening other tabs and come back the same tab.

Certainly said, when I select tab, I show new price with animation but it's not  repeating when I select other tabs and come back to the same tab.

See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/jn9v3j1c/

HTML:

```
 <div class="price">
             <h2 class="heading price-old">300</h2>
             <h2 class="heading fade price-discount">90</h2>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab

    if (e.target) {
        $(this).siblings().children('.price-old').animate({
            fontSize: "30px"
        });
        $('.price-discount').addClass('in');
    }

});
```

Please don't judge my code much, I do my first steps in JS :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to work, after a few fixes.

First of all, `this` in jQuery callbacks refers to the element(s) which caught the event. Here, it's the `a` element, but you don't want the `siblings` of the `a` element. You want to look for the tab itself:

```
var tab = $($(this).attr("href"));
```

Next, the `.price-old` is not a (direct) child, it's a descendant, you should use the **`find`** method:

```
tab.siblings().find('.price-old').animate({
        fontSize: "30px"
    });
```

Then it seems to work, only `30px` is the original size, so I changed it to 20 - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/jn9v3j1c/2/)

Comment: Thanks for answer, this helps me a bit, btw my main problem still exists. The font-size and 90 is not updating on each tab click, when I switch to tab 2nd and then return to 1st, I already see 90, but it should appear with animation only after selecting his parent tab (rudely said it should be removed after switching another tab and appear again when I select its parent tab)

Comment: Sorry :( I can't figure out what result you're trying to get. Can you try explaining again?

Comment: Sorry maybe I describe not well. See this small gif  https://gyazo.com/c1c1a7a8f06eb2f658db25376c7a68d6 . When I refresh the page and switch the tab "Profile", "90" is appearing, that's fine. But when I switch the tab "Messages", 90 should be hidden again and appear with animation. So the same action should be repeated again, like after refreshing the page. Does that make sense?

Comment: great!! couldn't guess that I changed class commonly for all tabs. only one minor problem, animation working only when you open tabs for the first time, is there a solution to show it on every time, not just the first?

Comment: Apparently the `siblings` was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ramanbedi1989/jn9v3j1c/6/) fiddle. I have made the animation on 90 to reappear every time you click the tab again.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab

    if (e.target) {
        var tab = $($(this).attr("href"));
        tab.find('.price-old').animate({
            fontSize: "20px"
        });
        tab.find('.price-discount').addClass('in');
    }



});
```